# C # calls yolov4 target detection and encounters this problem. How can I solve it?

Tags: yolo

cuDNN status Error in: file: d:\yolo\darknet-master\darknet-master\src\convolutional_layer.c : cudnn_convolutional_setup() : line: 253 : build time: Jul 31 2021 - 17:26:08

cuDNN Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM

Answer (score 0):

Got same error after updating darknet and solved it with several actions:

- Configure c# app to target platform x64
- Modify the api calls in c# to match the function signs in lib

Actions may help:

- Verify cuda and cudnn version
- Rebuild darknet